# Найти Наименьший Делитель

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Прохожу уроки на Hexlet и столкнулся с темой "*итеративный процесс*".
Думаю, что в моем коде (см. ниже) не хватает ещё нескольких условий (инструкций) для его грамотного выполнения.

Не прошу выполнить всё за меня, но прошу дать наводку или объяснить, чего не хватает. **ГОТОВЫЙ КОД МНЕ НЕ НУЖЕН!**

```js
const nod = (num) => {
  const iter = (delitel, acc) => {
    if (delitel === 1) {
      return acc
    }
    return iter(delitel - 1, acc % delitel)
  }
  return iter(5, num)
}
console.log(nod(15));
```

Comment: Сложно дать наводку или что-то объяснить, когда неясно, что именно требуется объяснить.

Comment: По заданию, при вызове **_nod (15)_** - например - в консоли должно появляться число ***3***
  
В моём коде явно не хватает каких-то доп. условий (инструкций) для его грамотного выполнения.  
Вот я и не могу понять, что нужно добавить.

Comment: @pornhubchristmasclub, а почему результат для nod(15) должен быть 3? Какой именно алгоритм ты пытаешься реализовать?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как вообще может быть найменьший ОБЩИЙ делитель у одного числа?

Comment: может ты хочешь найти наименьший делитель?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, там внутри второе зашито :-)

Comment: да, я ошибся в написании)) найти нужно Наименьший делитель

Comment: @Grundy ну потому что наименьший делитель для 15 - это 3. какой алгоритм я пытаюсь реализовать? рекурсию в итеративном процессе

Comment: @pornhubchristmasclub, тогда опиши алгоритм, который у тебя в коде, и почему жестко зашито число 5?

Comment: твоя функция сейчас вполне заменяется одним выражением `15%5`

Comment: @Grundy ну по моей идее, я вкидываю число 5, программа должна перебрать числа от 1 до 5, и собственно первое попавшееся число, на которое будет делиться 15 и есть ответ. То есть от 1 до 5 первое число, на которое делиться 15 это 3

Comment: @Grundy моя функция заменяется сейчас 15 / 5. А 15 % 5 - это 0.

Comment: алгоритм достаточно простой - начиная с `2` перебирать числа до квадратного корня от `num` и проверять есть ли остаток, если остатка нет, то это нужное число

Comment: @pornhubchristmasclub, правильно и именно 0 она у тебя сейчас и выводит :)

Comment: @Grundy а мне нужно 3. в теории то как бы всё понятно, но на практике как это реализовать я пока не понимаю :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const nd = (num, div = 1) => num % ++div ? nd(num, div) : div;

console.log(nd(15));
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью рекурсии это можно сделать так

```js
const node = (num) => {
  const iter = (divider = 2) => {
    if (divider * divider > num) {
      return num;
    }
    if (num % divider) {
      return iter(divider + 1);
    }
    return divider;
  }
  return iter();
}
console.log(node(15));
```

Comment: У меня вопрос - в ответе, который дал [@Vladimir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/937694), имеется строчка: if (num % divider) { так вот, насколько я понимаю, это условие, в условии должна быть вторая половина, что то типа `if (num % divider **!==0**) {` и тогда мне это условие становится понятно. Но здесь его нет, но код все равно работает.
Огромная просьба - посните пожалуйста, как и почему это получается? И еще по ходу выполнения прошу помочь с прояснением. Верно ли мое понимание происходящего: const node = (num) => { const iter = (divider = 2) => { if (divider * divider > num) { return num;

Answer (score 0):

Как я помню из [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) итеративный процесс это рекурсия в которой рекурсивный вызов - последнее действие в функции.  Это ещё называется [хвостовая рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Тогда задачу можно решить например так:

```
const least_divisor = n => {
    const iter = d => {
        if (n % d === 0) {
            return d;
        }
        return iter(d + 1);
    }
    return iter(2);
};
```

Хвостовая рекурсия в функции с говорящим названием `iter`.

Или можно перебирать делители с другого конца. Выглядит странно, но работает:

```
const least_divisor = n => {
    const iter = (d, least_d) => {
        if (d === 1) {
            return least_d;
        }
        if (n % d === 0) {
            least_d = d;
        }
        return iter(d - 1, least_d);
    }
    return iter(n - 1, n);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const smallestDivisor = (num) => {
  if (num % 2 === 0 && num > 0) {
    return 2;
  } else if (num <= 0) {
    return NaN;
  } else if (num === 1) {
    return num;
  }
  // Проверки на корректный ввод данных для значения "num"
  const devider = (count = 2) => {
    /* Если "Num" делится на значение "devider" с остатком 
       (остаток от деления не равен 0,  к значению делителя 
       прибовляем (+1) */
    if (num % count !== 0) {
      return devider(count + 1);
    } else {
      /* Дефолтное значение (если остаток от деления равен 0, 
         count остается прежним) */
      return count;
    }
  }
  return devider();
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).