# Помогите понять как работает код итеративного процесса (разбор кода пошагово)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Всем доброго дня. У меня вопрос к сообществу.
Имеется код в ответе, который дал [@Vladimir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/937694), вот [ссылка на страницу с ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin). Так вот в ответе имеется строчка:

```
if (num % divider) {
```

насколько я понимаю, это условие, в условии должна быть вторая половина, что то типа   `if (num % divider **!==0) {` и тогда мне это условие становится понятно. Но здесь его нет, но код все равно работает.
Огромная просьба - поясните пожалуйста, как и почему это получается?

И еще по ходу выполнения прошу помочь с прояснением. Верно ли мое понимание происходящего:

```
const node = (num) => { 
  const iter = (divider = 2) => {
    if (divider * divider > num) {
      return num; // Проверяем есть ли делитель кроме самого числа
    }
    if (num % divider) { 
      return iter(divider + 1); // Проверяем получается ли при делении числа из функции на divider целое число. Если нет, то divider +1
    }
    return divider; // Эта часть перезапускает данный if и плюсует к divider единицу до того момента, пока условие не будет выполнено
  }
  return iter(); //когда предыдущий if закончил цикл (число, делящее без остатка найдено), возвращаемся к функции iter 
}
console.log(node(15));
```

при обращении к `node()` запускаем весь процесс и выводим ответ на экран.

Comment: Ненулевое значение в `if (...)` трактуется как истинное, нулевое - как ложное. Значит, `num % divider` дает истину тогда и только тогда, когда оно не равно нулю, так что `if (num % divider)` и `if (num % divider != 0)` попросту эквивалентны.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за пояснения! Можете еще дать комментарий по моему видению хода выполнения алгоритма?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var b = new Boolean(0);
console.log(typeof b.valueOf(), b.valueOf());
var b1 = new Boolean(3);
console.log(typeof b1.valueOf(), b1.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 1):

По просьбе прокомментировать понимание...

```
const node = (num) => { 
  const iter = (divider = 2) => {
    if (divider * divider > num) {
      return num; // Если добрались до значения, большего квадратного корня из num
                  // и ничего не нашли - значит, число простое, возвращаем его 
    }
    if (num % divider) { 
      return iter(divider + 1); // Если число НЕ делится на divider - значит, это
                                // не делитель, и надо рекурсивно проверять
                                // делитель, на 1 больший
    }
    return divider;  // Сюда мы попадаем, если num % divider в предыдущем if равен 0,
                     // т.е. если num  делится на divider - в этом случае возвращаем
                     // найденный делитель divider
  }
  return iter();   // Не настолько знаю javascript, чтобы прокомментировать этот вызов
}
console.log(node(15));
```

Но сам алгоритм неэффективный и слишком расточительный в смысле стека... Такая глубокая рекурсия может плохо кончиться.